# copying few lines from one text to other by batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO off
C:
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin"
SED = "G:\mini thesis\New folder\input.txt" > "G:\mini thesis\New folder\output.txt"
sed 1p,3p G:\mini thesis\New folder\input.txt>G:\mini thesis\New folder\output.txt
```

This code copies all the lines from input to output, and I don't know I what's wrong.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal

( set /P "line1=" & set /P "line2=" ) < input.txt
(
   echo %line1%
   echo %line2%
) > output.txt
```

I want to copy from 22nd line to 84th line, but I don't know which syntax to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hybrid code Batch and vbscript to achieve your aim :

```
@echo off
Rem Just Change those params to yours ie InputFile and OutPutFile
Set "InputFile=C:\temp\Input.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=C:\temp\Output.txt"
Set FromLine=22
Set ToLine=84
::********************************************************************************************************
Call:ExtractLinesFromTextFile "%InputFile%" %FromLine% %ToLine% > "%OutPutFile%"
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%"
Exit /b
::********************************************************************************************************
:ExtractLinesFromTextFile <InputFile> <FromLine> <ToLine>
(
    echo Wscript.echo(ExtractLinesFromTextFile("%~1",%2,%3^)^)
    echo Function ExtractLinesFromTextFile(TextFile,FromLine,ToLine^)
    echo     If FromLine ^<= ToLine Then
    echo         With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^).OpenTextFile(TextFile^)
    echo             Do Until .Line = FromLine Or .AtEndOfStream
    echo                 .SkipLine
    echo             Loop
    echo             Do Until .Line ^> ToLine Or .AtEndOfStream
    echo                 ExtractLinesFromTextFile = ExtractLinesFromTextFile ^& (.ReadLine ^& vbNewLine^)
    echo             Loop
    echo         End With
    echo     Else
    echo         Wscript.echo "Lines overflow error", vbCritical, "Lines overflow error"
    echo     End If
    echo End Function
)>"%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /Nologo "%~n0.vbs" "%~1" %~2 %~3
If Exist "%~n0.vbs" Del "%~n0.vbs"
Exit /b
::********************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a certain line from a text file, use `for /F` with the `skip` option and `goto` to break the loop. Each line is preceded with a line number by `findstr` intermittently in order not to lose empty lines:

```dos
rem This reads the 22nd line of a text file:
for /F "skip=21 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "input.txt"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LINE:*:=!
    endlocal
    goto :CONT
)
:CONT
```

To write (replace) a certain line to (in) a text file, you need to read the text, replace the line and to write the result to an interim (temporary) file; finally, move the interim file onto the original file (and overwrite it). The sub-routine `:SUB` basically contains the above code fragment:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "INFILE=input.txt"
set "OUTFILE=output.txt"
set "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\interim.txt"
set "INLINE=22"
set "OUTLINE=84"

rem This reads a text file and replaces a certain line:
> "%TEMPFILE%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%OUTFILE%"') do (
        set "LINE=%%F"
        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ("%%F") do set "LNUM=%%N"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !LNUM! EQU %OUTLINE% (
            call :SUB
        ) else (
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
> nul 2>&1 move /Y "%TEMPFILE%" "%OUTFILE%"

endlocal
exit /B

:SUB
rem This reads a certain line from a text file:
set /A SKIP=INLINE-1
if %SKIP% GTR 0 (set "SKIP=skip=%SKIP% ") else (set "SKIP=")
for /F "%SKIP%delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%INFILE%"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LINE:*:=!
    endlocal
    goto :EOF
)
```